# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_xml'

Tags: python, bs4

Я парсю дату с [этого портала](https://kapital.kz/news/).Эту часть 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Для этого написал такой код:

```
def get_item_datetime(item_page, resource_page, datetime_main_rule, datetime_rule, datetime1_rule):
    # < Проверка item_page на None.
    if item_page is None:
        return
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, resource_page,  'lxml')
    main_page_datetime = soup.find(datetime_main_rule[0],{datetime_main_rule[1]:datetime_main_rule[2]})
    if (len(datetime_main_rule) == 3):
        main_page_datetime = soup.find(datetime_main_rule[0],{datetime_main_rule[1]:datetime_main_rule[2]})
    else:
        item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]})
        if item_datetime is not None:
            item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]}).text
            item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
        else:
            if (len(datetime1_rule) == 3):
                item_datetime = soup.find(datetime1_rule[0],{datetime1_rule[1]:datetime1_rule[2]}).text
                item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
            else:
                item_datetime = ''
            return (main_page_datetime,item_datetime)
```

В этом месте я парсю  именно с [этой страницы](https://kapital.kz/news/) дату:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, resource_page,  'lxml')
    main_page_datetime = soup.find(datetime_main_rule[0],{datetime_main_rule[1]:datetime_main_rule[2]})
    if (len(datetime_main_rule) == 3):
        main_page_datetime = soup.find(datetime_main_rule[0],{datetime_main_rule[1]:datetime_main_rule[2]})
```

В `item_page`у меня хранятся **html** данные с [этой страницы](https://kapital.kz/business/80961/kak-razvivaet-biznes-edinstvennyj-proizvoditel-bytovoj-himii-zko.html) для bs4

В `resource_page` у меня хранятся **html** данные с этой [главной страницы](https://kapital.kz/news/)  для bs4

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 146, in <module>
    call_all_func(resources)
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 128, in call_all_func
    item_datetime = get_item_datetime(item_page,resource_page,datetime_main_rule,datetime_rule,datetime1_rule)
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 48, in get_item_datetime
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, resource_page,  'lxml')
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 258, in __init__
    self.is_xml = builder.is_xml
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_xml'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Единственное что я понял,так это 
у объекта 'str' нет атрибута 'is_xml'

Откуда начать копать?

P.S:Читал документацию bs4 ничего такого там не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по документации у `BeautifulSoup` первые 3 аргумента следующие: `markup`, `features` и `builder`.

1. `markup` для HTML-верстки (у вас это `item_page`);
2. `features` для парсера (у вас это `resource_page`, но должен быть `lxml`);
3. `builder` для подкласса `TreeBuilder`.

Таким образом у вас должно быть вот так:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
```